# Running Bash Script on Cron: Centos7

Tags: linux, bash, centos7

I have the the following script on below which will send a desktop notification on how full the /tmp and /var/tmp directories are to run on a Cron. Below is the script.

```
tmpsize=`du -sm /tmp | cut -f1`
varsize=`du -sm /var/tmp | cut -f1`

if { [ $tmpsize -gt 1024 ] && [ $tmpsize -lt 7001 ]; } || { [ $varsize -gt 1024 ] && [ $varsize -lt 7001 ]; } then
/usr/bin/notify-send -- "Disk Warning" "/tmp folder is ${tmpsize}MB\n/var/tmp is ${varsize}MB"

elif [ $tmpsize -gt 7000 ] || [ $varsize -gt 7000 ] ; then
/usr/bin/notify-send -- "Disk Warning" "/tmp folder it ${tmpsize}MB out of 8GB\n/var/tmp is ${varsize}MB out of 8GB\n/Please Clear out your /tmp using rm -rf /tmp and your /var/tmp using rm -rf /var/tmp"

else
/usr/bin/notify-send -- "Disk Warning" "All clear ${tmpsize}MB"

fi
```

When running this bash script on my shell it runs perfectly, as well as running this as root.
I am using the following cron: `sudo crontab -e`  in order to make this run on my Centos7 machine. `*/1 * * * * PATH/to/file/user/tmp_warning.sh`. However with this cron running every min the notication doesn't show up on my desk top. I even tried with using `DISPLAY=:0` within the cron. I also checked the `/var/log/cron` For which the cron was running without any issues. Any ideas on what i am missing?

Comment: Redirect to a log file to see what errors are showing.

Comment: try */1 * * * *  bash PATH/to/file/user/tmp_warning.sh

Comment: @AmineBouzid luck with using ```bash``` infront of the path

Comment: @RamanSailopal I redirected it to a log file and there are no errors shown up.